# Is there any advantage to using socket.io over a simple HTTP HEAD request from a browser to server with Javascript to measure internet ping speed?

Tags: http, socket.io, ping, latency

I'm trying to calculate the ping speed from a client to a server. 
I'm creating a complete application, so I'm writing the server logic as well. I'm wondering if I should use socket.io to ping the server from the client, or simply send a random HTTP HEAD request to the server, and if any of them is more accurate than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the frequency of the ping I guess. For a simple ping every so often, I would probably just fire off an http request as needed.

Every connection requires resources so x many clients connected require x connected sockets being managed which has some overhead. This may not be an issue given your anticipated quantity of concurrent users, but you would get away using fewer server resources having clients connect via http.

If you making the rest of your calls via http, then it makes sense to have a more accurate measurement using the same protocol.